# How to access individual fields within struct array

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to complete an assignment and I'm having trouble with the following (I have worked on this for the last 12 hours). Please help.

I have opened a file, saved the file into an struct array. Can access each element of the struct but don't know how I can access each individual field. i.e

Struct

```
//struct to hold the hand values
public struct CurrentHand
{
    public char cardSuit;
    public int cardValue;
}
```

I need to extract the `cardValue` into an array or variables so I can evaluate each record i.e. is the hand a pair or two pair etc. I have no idea how to do this. From what I have found its not possible to access each field, is this true?

```
        //Open file and load data into array
    public static void LoadHandData(CurrentHand[] handData, string fileName)
    {
        string input = ""; //temporary variable to hold one line of data
        string[] cardData; //temporary array to hold data split from input

        //Open the file and read the contents
        StreamReader readHand = new StreamReader(fileName);

        input = readHand.ReadLine(); //one record
        cardData = input.Split(' '); //split record into fields

        for (int counter = 0; counter < handData.Length; counter++)
        {
            handData[counter].cardSuit = Convert.ToChar(cardData[counter *2]);
            handData[counter].cardValue = Convert.ToInt16(cardData[counter *2 +1]);
        }
        readHand.Close();
    }
```

Comment: ... isn't it that maybe you want your method to actually return an array of CurrentHand with the data you read from the file? That piece of code makes things harder to understand...

Comment: Thanks Tim. StreamReader is the what the text tells me to use. (filename) is the name of the file I'm reading from which is passed from another method and the files only contain on line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain an array containing the values of the cards you hold in your hand, you can do:

```
var values = handData.Select(x=>x.cardValue).ToArray();
var seeds = handData.Select(x=>x.cardSuit).ToArray();
```

By the way, your struct should be called Card or something like that, since an Hand is supposed to be a collection of cards. The name you gave to it is just confusing and makes your code less readeable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The struct holds 5 cards each having a suit and value.

Comment: That must be a different struct, since the one you posted only has 2 properties, and really looks like a card struct.

Comment: Added the method that opens file and save data.

Comment: I have update the code in the solution. values will be an array of int containing your cardvalues, and seeds will be an array of char containing the seeds of the cards. I keep thinking that the struct should be called Card.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear to me. anyway you can access invidual fields using .
try this...

```
CurrentHand.cardValue
```

using above you can get and set value for CurrentHand structure.